# How to use third part modules in react integrated in my website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use react to replace parts of an already-existing website. I've successfully implemented simple code but now I want to use third-part packages. Let's say for example the [@iconify/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@iconify/react).
Following [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) I've run in my terminal:

```
npm init -y
npm install babel-cli@6 babel-preset-react-app@3
npm install --save-dev @iconify/react @iconify-icons/octicon
npx babel --watch src --out-dir ../main/static/react/ --presets react-app/prod
```

in src directory I have this file called loginBox.jsx

```
import { Icon, InlineIcon } from '@iconify/react';
import Squirrel16 from '@iconify-icons/octicon/squirrel-16';

const LoginBox = (props) => {
...
return (
    <div>
        <Icon icon={Squirrel16} />
    </div>
);
}
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#loginBoxContainer');
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(LoginBox), domContainer);
```

However console show an error coming from the first line (actually the 3rd of the corresponding .js file).

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

My question is: **how can I use third-part modules in this context?**

*EDIT 1:*
this is my package.json in root folder (main/static/react/)

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@iconify-icons/octicon": "^1.1.3",
    "@iconify/react": "^1.1.4"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

I added "type":"module" but still I'm getting this output

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood what the problem was. I made confusion because I'm new to react and even more to node. I installed iconify via npm but that was not enought because I was using node only as a compiler. In order to achieve my goal I need also a bundler (which now I'll look for). I was completery unaware of this because in my last project I used `create-react-app` that did all of that for me.

Useful links:

- [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#more-flexible-toolchains)
- [useful article](https://blog.usejournal.com/creating-a-react-app-from-scratch-f3c693b84658)

Answer (score 1):

add `type:"module"` to your package.json. Or use `require` to import npm modules. `import` was introduced in ES6, and so you must set type in package.json or it will infer that you are using commonJS, when its not set. Therefore syntax error, because import doesn't exist in commonJS.

You can read more about it [here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_package_json_type_field)

Comment: still don't gettin it. I added type="module" in my <script> tag so now it looks like this: <script type="module" src="{% static 'react/loginBox.js' %}"></script>. Now console output this error: *Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@iconify/react". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".* What am I missing?

Comment: Not in the script tags. In the package.json file. Do you have a package.json file in the root dir? Add this in that file.

Comment: yes I have it, I edited the question so you can see package.json.

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: node v14.15.4
website is build with python 3.9.0 / django 3.1.5

Comment: I dont really understand your setup. How are you building your react files? With node or python? There's no build or start script in your package.json. How are you even generating the bundle.js I am not very sure what's going on. But, to answer your question, change `import` to `require`. `const Icon = require('@iconify/react')` also remove the `type:"module" that I asked you to add to the script or you will get an error if you use `require` with type:module. I think Youtube and Medium can help more than stackoverflow.